# Python Requests returning 503 response

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using Requests to parse some data on a server. However, I keep getting a 503 response. The request headers have cookies in them, but my method does not seem to be handling them properly.

I am also a bit confused as to what I should be doing with cookies and when full stop. The website is `http://epgservices.sky.com/nevermiss/`and my code is below.

Headers and params look correct when viewed in Google Dev Tools, other than the cookies are missing when I use Requests. Any ideas?

```
import json
import requests
from urllib3.util import Retry
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests import Session, exceptions
import re
import traceback
from cookielib import LWPCookieJar


class sky_ondemand:

    session = requests.Session()
    jar = session.cookies


    url = 'http://epgservices.sky.com'

    movie_path = ''.join(movie_path)

    headers = {
    'Host': 'epgservices.sky.com',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.119 Safari/537.36',
    'Referer': 'http://epgservices.sky.com/never-miss/index.htm',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8'
    }

    params = {
    'queryType': 'movieQuery',
    'query': '',
    'exactMatch': 'false',
    'genre': '',
    'startsWith': 'all',
    'sortBy': 'requested',
    'pageNum': '1',
    'pageSize': '10',
    'src': 'movieLetterButton'
    }

    r = session.get(url, params=params, headers=headers, cookies=jar)

    data = r.content
    print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorted this if anyone is interested....was nothing to do with the cookies...the url should have been 'http://epgservices.sky.com/tvlistings-proxy/NeverMissProxy/neverMissMovieSearchRequest.json?'